# Booking website has changed a part of my flight, can I ask a full refund?

Tags: online-resources, bookings, refunds

I have booked flight from broker, flight is from Riga RIX to Goa GOI, now part of my trip has changed.

> 3 9W2354H 24APR MAA GOI   1035  1315 (cancelled flight)   4 9W2305H
>   24APR MAA BLR   0820  0910   (new flight)
>
> 5 9W 498H 24APR  BLR GOI    1025  1140   (new flight)
>
> 6 9W 427H 05MAY GOI BOM    1855  2005  (cancelled flight)
>
> 7 9W2374H 05MAY GOI BOM   0545  0700  (new flight)

Broker offers only partial refund (full price was 550 Eur)

We would like to inform you that unfortunately the airline company does not accept the request for full refund in case of cancellation so according the airline's rules your e-ticket fare is non-refundable. The refundable amount is 85.62 € for both passengers. This amount will be reimbursed within a maximum of 30 working days after the airline's authorization. For any change or cancellation our agency charges 30.00 €.

Now we prefer not to take a flight at all, may i ask a full refund because a part of booking has be changed?

Comment: It depends on the broker's terms and conditions.

Comment: Who is the broker?

Comment: Airtickets24 broker

Answer (score 3):

It's probably not the broker who changed the flight but the airline, which indeed has the right to cancel and/or reschedule flights. However **it would seem that, according to [the FAQ page from AirTicket24](http://www.airtickets24.com/misc/faq), you can ask for compensation in case of substantial changes**:

> #### 23. What happens if the airline changes its flights?
>
> The airlines are sometimes forced to modify the itineraries, hours and number of their flights. In this case we will try to inform you for any changes before the date of departure so that you adjust your program to these changes. These changes are usually of minor importance without significant impact on your trip. If significant changes occur related to your flight (for example change in departure time for more than 2 hours or change of departure airport) and you have no alternative that suits you then you can request compensation from the airline, according to the passenger's rights established by the European Union, unless you have been informed on time by the airline.

Hence I would go ahead and contact both your broker, quoting the FAQ, add well as your airline to see what can be arranged.